# SpringMVC - CORS filtering doesn't work on 'Authorization' header

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, oauth-2.0, angular5

I am trying to add OAuth 2.0 in spring mvc app. User should be authenticated in order to get a api call. I have set a headers in spring mvc controller as:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin-api/get-all-order", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity getAllOrders(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String bearerToken) {
        try {
            List<OrderModel> order = orderService.getAllOrders();
            return new ResponseEntity(order, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            return new ResponseEntity(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
```

For requesting api I have used angular 5. I make a api call in angular like:

```
return this.http.get<T>(this.getAllOrderUrl, {
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "bearer " + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token"))["value"],
                "Content-type": "application/json"
            }
        }).catch(error => {
            return this.auth.handleError(error);
        })
```

But it gave me a strange error.
[image]

I have already enabled a CORS for 'localhost:4200'. CORS filtering works fine on other request.

```
@Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                "ACL, CANCELUPLOAD, CHECKIN, CHECKOUT, COPY, DELETE, GET, HEAD, LOCK, MKCALENDAR, MKCOL, MOVE, OPTIONS, POST, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, PUT, REPORT, SEARCH, UNCHECKOUT, UNLOCK, UPDATE, VERSION-CONTROL");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                "X-PINGOTHER,Content-Type,X-Requested-With,Accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Authorization,Key");

        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }
```

If I tried in postman it give me a desired result.
[image]

**Response Header**
[image]

What am I doing wrong? Please help me out. Hoping for positive response thanks!

Comment: You didn't make a `OPTIONS` call in Postman. Try it again with `OPTIONS`.

Comment: It doesn't return anything. Do you know any idea to solve this issue

Comment: `OPTION` calls don't return any body, only headers. That's ok.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable CORS without using filters or without config file just add

```
@CrossOrigin
```

to the top of your controller and it work.

Comment: This even does't solve my issue